# Honda CBR150 Race Bike Engine Problems

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, starting

I have a Honda CBR150 race bike with some engine problems. The bike struggles to start, think of the way a carburetor bike would struggle to start if it hasn't been run in a long time, but it does it all the time regardless of how recently it's been run.

To get it to start you have to patiently crank it multiple times in short bursts (so as to not burnout the starter). EVENTUALLY(30min - an hour later), it does start, but even then, it stalls at anything below 2,000rpm until the engine is warm. Once the engine is warm, it runs fine. But as soon as you switch the bike off, you're back to square one.

I have previously taken the tank off, cleaned the fuel pump and filter, completely disassembled the carburetor, cleaned it and put it all back together. All of this actually got the bike to start first crank... until 2 days later when it was back to it's old ways.

Where do I go from here? Should I replace the carburetor? What else can I check?

Thanks in advance
Willem